# Is there a policy on the use of emojis or emoticons?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any policy on the use of emojis or emoticons?

Examples:

[Can't login with my PIN password in Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105265/i-cant-login-please-help-me)

[image: In title of question]

In https://askubuntu.com/posts/1105109/revisions it was part of the code until the querist removed it

[image: In code]

Comment: Related on MSE: [Do we want emojis in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299922)

Comment: In that particular situation the lips were OP's shell prompt. Bizarre, and confusing, but _technically_ the emoji had an Ubuntu-related meaning.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Right, but of course, replacing it with `$` would clear all confusion and thus be the right thing to do for an editor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the existing rules apply: if something isn't adding relevant information to a post, it is noise and it is better to remove it. Unless a question is actually about emojis, they don't add anything useful to a post, so I don't see why they should be treated any differently to any other type of noise.

More importantly, emojis often don't render correctly across different browsers and platforms, making it an even worse idea to include them in posts. So no, please don't include emojis in AU questions or answers unless they really are necessary for some reason.